# How to get the list of audiences using the start-index parameter

Tags: python, api, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I want to get the audience list when requesting from Python starting from 1001 positions. On the Google Management API site there is an article saying that you can use additional options. But when using the

```
audiences = service.management().remarketingAudience().list(
accountId='111111',  
webPropertyId='UA-111111-1'
max-results=1000,
start-index=1001
). execute()
```

You get an error: max-results=1000, SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: Yes, start_index & max_results work.
Thank you!